# Haskell: Comparing Characters

Tags: haskell, char, boolean, haskell-platform

I want to create a function consonant which check, whether an char is an consonant(True) or a vowel(False).
I try something like this:

```
consonant :: Char -> Bool
consonant x = if (x == 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u'|' ') then False else True
```

But it doesn't work, i think it is just a problem with the Syntax.
I hope anyone can help me :)
Thanks

Comment: A space is a consonant?

Comment: @chepner well... no, it's a non-consonant! Interesting that “A”, “ω” and “⌘” seem to be consonants though...

Comment: Oops, yeah, I read that backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `x == 'a'|'e'|'i'|'o'|'u'|' '` does not make sense, the pipe character (`|`) is used for guards, or when defining several data constructors for a data type.

Replacing `|` with [**`(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-124--124-) will not help either, since `'e'` is not a `Bool`. We can however write several conditions:

```
consonant :: Char -> Bool
consonant x = not (x == 'a'|| x == 'e'|| x == 'i'|| x =='o'|| x =='u'|| x ==' ')
```

or we can make use of [**`elem :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem):

```
consonant :: Char -> Bool
consonant = not . flip elem "aeiou "
```

or we can make use of an operator sectioning as [@leftroundabout suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590808/haskell-comparing-characters/58590885?noredirect=1#comment103496449_58590885):

```
consonant :: Char -> Bool
consonant = not . (`elem` "aeiou ")
```

or do the "flipping" ourselves with a variable:

```
consonant :: Char -> Bool
consonant x = not (elem x "aeiou ")
```

Or we can make use [**`notElem :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:notElem) which negates the `elem`:

```
consonant :: Char -> Bool
consonant = (`notElem` "aeiou ")
```

Comment: I prefer ``consonant = (`elem`"aeiou ")``. I generally find `flip` awkward, often it's better to just introduce a binding rather than taking point-free to the extreme.

Comment: I used to think that consonant x = elem x "bcdfghjklmnpqrtuvwxz", but I am not a native speaker of English; that comes a long way towards explaining why we can't understand native speakers.

Comment: @jpmarinier: you are right, somehow, I lost track of the "not" through the `if`-`then`-`else`.